# Numerical implementation of ODE differs largely from analytical solution

Tags: python, numerical-methods, differential-equations

I am trying to solve the ODE of a free fall including air resistance.

I therefore defined my ODE as:

```
def f(v, g, k, m):
    return g - k/m * v**2
```

which in my opinion should represent the system correctly because

```
m*a = m*g -k*v**2
```

where `a=vdot`.

Now I solve this ODE using the explicit Euler method like this:

```
h = 0.1
t = np.arange(0, 1000 + h, h)
v0 = 0

g = 9.81
k = 0.1
m = 1.

# Explicit Euler Method
v_num = np.zeros(len(t))
v_num[0] = 0

x_num = np.zeros(len(t))
x_num[0] = 100

for i in range(0, len(t) - 1):
    v_num[i + 1] = v_num[i] + h*f(v_num[i], g, k, m)
    x_num[i + 1] = x_num[i] - v_num[i + 1] * h
```

On first glance this seems to work fine. However I plotted it against the analytical solution of the ODE that I found online

```
v_ana = m*g*(1.-np.exp(-k/m*t))/k
```

And they seem to differ largely, as shown below.

[image: Chart of numerical and analytical solution of ODE. Analytical solution reaches much higher terminal velocity]

Where did I go wrong here?

Comment: While I am not an expert, I believe your equations for x(t) and v(t) don't seem quite right to me.  So I would start with going back to the basics, and computing the V(t) and x(t) for the initial sequence of values, then use the result of these calculations to compare against what you calculate for x and v.

Comment: Hi @itprorh66 thanks for your comment! Do you mean the differential equation `vdot = g - k/m * v**2` or the analytical solution `v_ana = m*g*(1.-np.exp(-k/m*t))/k`? I would for now ignore the calculation for `x` because if `v` is not correct, then obviously `x` will also not be correct.

Comment: I found the issue. I implemented the low Re analytical solution and compared it to the high Re numerical solution. Obv. these differ.

Comment: Please do not or mark cross-postings. Here to https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/43370/numerical-implementation-of-ode-differs-largely-from-analytical-solution/43373#43373. Ironically I believe that the least off-topic place for this question would be math.SE, as its numerical content is rather basic, and no coding error was committed or observed. So the question is really about the reference or analytical solution.

Comment: @Axel, your analytical solution should be v=(beta/k)tanh(beta.t) and x=(1/k)ln(cosh(beta.t)), where beta=sqrt(m.g.k). Obviously, there's a few different ways of writing that. The analytical solution that you give is to the different differential equation with k.v rather than k.v**2 in the expression for resistive force.

Comment: @lastchance Yup, the analytical solution that I found was for small Reynolds numbers where the drag is proportional to v and not v**2. I found an analytical solution to the high Re problem in the meantime and it fits the numerical solution very nicely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The analytic solution you provide is the solution for the force

```
def f(v, g, k, m):                                                                                      
    return g - k * v / m
```

Note the absence of a squared `v`. Once you fix that, both solutions coincide.
[image]